# Hessian of an Ellipsoid seems invariate

Tags: multivariable-calculus, conic-sections, hessian-matrix, quadrics

An ellipsoid is the hypersurface of the ellipse in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which belongs to the family of quadrics. It is defined by a quadratic form equating to 1 in its canonical (unrotated) form.

$\vec{x}^T D \vec{x} = 1$

where $D$ is a diagonal, positive definite matrix. In non-vector form it is represented by,

$\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^2} + \frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^2} + \frac{(z-z_0)^2}{c^2} = 1$

where $x$, $y$, $z$ are the Cartesian coordinates of a point on its surface, $x_0$, $y_0$ and $z_0$ are the coordinates of its centroid and $a$, $b$ and $c$ are its semi-axis lengths.

The Hessian matrix is the matrix which holds all possible second order derivative information for a multi-variable scalar function $f$.

\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial z} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y \partial z} \\
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial x} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z \partial y} & \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z^2}
\end{bmatrix}

Here's my question: I expect the Hessian to vary along the surface of the ellipsoid but when you actually calculate the Hessian matrix of a canonical ellipsoid, it is invariate i.e doesn't depend on the coordinate variables. Why?

Thanks in advance,
MotiveHunter

Comment: Second derivative of $x^2$ is a constant; you just stumbled upon a 3D generalization of this simple fact.

Comment: Agreed. So is it to be understood that the curvature of the ellipsoid is constant? That the Hessian at an extreme point (at points $\vec{x} = a \hat{e}_1$, $\vec{x} = b \hat{e}_2$ and $\vec{x} = c \hat{e}_3$) is the same as at any other point on the ellipsoid surface?

Thanks for replying!

Comment: Hessian of the quadratic form has ***totally*** nothing to do with the curvature of ellipsoid. The latter, of course, is not constant.

Comment: But isn't the Hessian of an ellipsoid's surface actually the carrier of second derivative information about the curvature of the ellipsoid? The gradient carries first derivative information.

Comment: I take back the "_totally nothing_" part. Indeed, the curvature has _something_ to do with second derivatives. That is, if you express your surface as $z=z(x,y)$, find the second derivatives and plug them into [certain expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_geometry_of_surfaces#Curvature_of_surfaces_in_Euclidean_space), you'll get the curvature(s). But those derivatives would not be constant, and neither will curvature. I guess you may derive the expression for curvature directly from the **implicit** equation that you have here, but it is going to be more complicated.